# Math Script variant in mtpro2

Tags: symbols, packages, mtpro, alphabet

Considering the [guide](http://tug.ctan.org/fonts/mtp2lite/texmf/doc/fonts/mtpro2/mtpro2.pdf) of `mtpro2` (full version) created by Walter Schmidt 2008/1/23, to pag. 8 (see the image below) there is the §2.8.

[image]

I think that to have for example the second column of **Fraktur**, we use `\mathfrak{\altx}`; to have the second column of **Curly** I think that the command is, for example, `\mathcal{\altQ}`.

What is, instead, the exact command to have the second column of **Script**, for example `\...{\altC}`?

My MWE and output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[mtpscr,mtpccal]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
$\mathscr{C}$, $\mathscr{\altC}$
$\mathcal{M}$, $\mathcal{\altM}$, $\mathfrak{X},\mathfrak{\altx}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The manual mentions the `mtpscr` package option: "**mtpscr** assigns Math Script to a new math alphabet `\mathscr`" in section 2.6 Calligraphic math alphabet.

Comment: @Marijn Please, can you add an answer of your precious comment to use the first and second columns?

Comment: I didn't install the package so I cannot try the solution myself. Maybe you can try if it works and post an answer to your own question, with an MWE and a screenshot of the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to load the (full) `mtpro2` package with the options

- `mtpscr`, to assign the mtpro "calligraphic" letters to the command `\mathscr`;
- `mtpccal`, to assign the mtpro "curly calligraphic" letters to the command `\mathcal`; and
- `mtpfrak`, to assign the mtpro "fraktur" letters to the command `\mathfrak`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[mtpscr,mtpccal,mtpfrak]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
\setlength\arraycolsep{10pt}
$\begin{array}{@{} *{6}{c} @{}}
\multicolumn{2}{@{}c}{$Script$} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$Curly$}     &
\multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{$Fraktur$} \\[1ex]
\mathscr{Y}  & \mathscr{\altY}  & 
\mathcal{Y}  & \mathcal{\altY}  & 
\mathfrak{Y} & \mathfrak{\altY}
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```