# How to access alternative shapes (e.g. `\altS`) in `mtpro2`?

Tags: fonts, symbols

I am able to access the normal shapes without loading `\mtpro2` (I have the full package including all the fonts) by defining

```
\newcommand{\Mathscr}[1]{\text{\usefont{U}{mt2ms}{m}{it}#1}}
```

and using the command inside an equation, e.g. `$\Mathscr{S}$`. The problem is that I don't know how to access the alternative shapes, e.g. `\altS` (see [here](http://tug.ctan.org/fonts/mtp2lite/texmf/doc/fonts/mtpro2/mtpro2.pdf), Section 2.8).

If I open the style file, e.g. [here](http://tug.ctan.org/fonts/mtp2lite/texmf/tex/latex/mtpro2/mtpro2.sty), there are a few definitions including those for the alternative shapes, but how can I access those by modifying my `\Mathscr` command? (or also defining `\altS` on its own in the preamble)

---

Edit: Alternatively, is it possible to access the alternative shapes via `\mathalfa`?

Comment: I think that this my question solve your: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506881/math-script-variant-in-mtpro2

Comment: Actually, by loading `mtpro2`, the entire math follows `mtpro2`, while I would only like to extract the fonts, say `\mathscr` alone. For example, the main math font becomes Times (or Times-like). I don't want that. I just want to access the calligraphic, script, fraktur fonts provided by `mtpro2`. Is it possible?

Comment: I have understood your request...you should to declare all the calligraphic, script, fraktur  symbols of mtpro2 and this is possible for my humble opinion. I am not able :-(. I can only upvoted you :-)

Comment: Thanks! I tried to define ```\DeclareMathSymbol{\altS}{\mathalpha}{letters}{'023}``` which seems to be the definition of `\MTP@S` but it doesn't work (in the sense that it shows a Greek letter).

Answer (score 1):

The `\DeclareMathSymbol` for `\altS` assumes a lot about the rest of the environment (in particular it also is assuming that you’d have selected the MathTime script font). I’m guessing you’d like to be able to just type `\altS` in math mode to get the symbol.

So you’ll need to do two things. First define a symbol font:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{Mathscr}{U}{mt2ms}{m}{it}
```

Then you’ll declare your symbol:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\altS}{\mathord}{Mathscr}{'023}
```

Two key differences between this and what you did: First, we specify the symbol font rather than `letters` so we don't need to do `\Mathscr` (and have it defined as a math alphabet). Second, we declare the character type as ord rather than letter so that it won't be affected by the current math alphabet.

An alternative approach would be to keep your definition of the symbol:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\altS}{\mathalpha}{letters}{'023}
```

but then define

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathscr}{U}{mt2ms}{m}{it}
```

Now you'd be able to do, e.g., `$\mathscr{\altS}$` as well as use `\mathscr` to access the rest of the MathTime script letters.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Don. Works beautifully. I will award the bounty as soon as possible.